# How to store data on topic which will be passed as a message through producer, such that it can loaded to database on respective columns

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra

I followed [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=bing&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.nonbrand_tp.rmkt_tgt.kafka_mt.xct_rgn.india_lng.eng_dv.all_con.kafka-spring&utm_term=spring%20kafka&creative=&device=c&placement=&msclkid=fb574f0256621aec4fb22e2787e3e53d) to produce a message on to topic using kafka spring so far.

The message I'm going to pass is just the name and now I would like to stream through this topic and add incremental value as ID along with name and store it on `OutputTopic` and now, I would like to store data to cassandra.

My table structure in cassandra as follows:-

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp(
   emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
   emp_name text,
   )
```

In which format the data should be on output topic so that I can easily store it on cassandra table?

How can I achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the data published on a Kafka topic, you can just use the DataStax [Kafka connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaIntro.html) for Apache Cassandra, DataStax Enterprise and [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf).

The connector lets you save records from a Kafka topic to Cassandra tables. It is open-source so it's free to use.

There's a [working example here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaTutorial.html) that includes a Cassandra table schema, details of how to configure the Kafka sink connector and map a topic to the CQL table. Cheers!